# Presented popover controller appears in wrong place

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

This what I use to present popover:

```
func presentPopoverController(controller: UIViewController, fromView view: UIView) {

    controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    controller.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(400, 400)

    let popover = controller.popoverPresentationController

    popover?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any

    print(view.frame)

    popover?.sourceView = view
    popover?.sourceRect = view.frame  //***

    presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is how it looks on screen:

[image]

And this is output on console:

> (326.0, 15.0, 63.0, 10.0)

If I remove the line with `***`then it looks like following, and is still in wrong place:

[image]

Output on console is same as above.

Answer (score 0):

There should be `popover?.sourceRect = view.bounds` instead of `view.frame`.